# Logar com o usuário do Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor

Como eu faço uma rotina em c# ou Razor em meu site, para ao invés do cara unicamente pelo login da página, ter a opção de logar pelo usuário do facebook?
Não estou pedindo código pronto, apenas como eu faço isso.

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nesses dois artigos. Acho que poderá ajudá-lo.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/autenticando-usuario-asp-net-mvc-facebook/